# Two errors during GDB installing on Mac El Capitan

Tags: macos, gdb, macports, codesign

My mac version is El Capitan 10.11.2 .

I have used macports to install gdb(actually it's ggdb).The info as follows: (I have installed gdb before this time, to do this because I just make sure I installed gdb. )

```
$ sudo port install gdb
--->  Computing dependencies for gdb
--->  Cleaning gdb
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors
--->  No broken files found.
```

And I have created my gdb key certificate,named ggdb. But when I try to use terminal to codesign my ggdb certificate by typing this command:

```
codesign -s ggdb /opt/local/bin/ggdb
```

Something wrong occurs !! Whether I quit taskgated or not, the error still appears as follow:

```
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate: can't create output file: /opt/local/bin/ggdb.cstemp (Permission denied)
/opt/local/bin/ggdb: the codesign_allocate helper tool cannot be found or used
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`codesign` is trying to write the file `ggdb.cstemp` to a directory (`/opt/local/bin/`) that you don't have permissions to write to. Try using `sudo` instead:

```
sudo codesign -s ggdb /opt/local/bin/ggdb
```